# Image not broken but not showing

Tags: html, image, tags, src, broken-image

I have this HTML:

```
<html>

  <head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.1/firebase.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="callback.js"></script>

  </head>

  <!-- Calls printResponse() when this page loads -->
  <body style="background-color: #ddeaff; text-align: center; margin-top: 100px">
    <img src="assets/bazlogofinal.png" height="720" width="720" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
    <div style="width: 100%; text-align: center; font-family: 'Helvetica'; font-size: 96px; color: #357aff; font-weight: 900">PLEASE WAIT...</div>
    <div id="url" style="display: none">
          <!-- empty URL for displaying response -->
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

The `src` for the `img` is correct, and the image isn't broken:

[image]

I have tried clearing the browser history on my phone.

Comment: If the image size is large it may still be loading in.

Comment: @NickParsons thanks I exported the image from photoshop with 'save for web' and it worked - must have been the filesize.

Comment: @NickParsons submit your comment as an answer and I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen when the image/file size is large (as it needs to load in the image). Try making the image/file size smaller.

You can make the image smaller using Photoshop’s save for web option or other lossless/lossy compression algorithms.